# Replace array object in NSMutableArray crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have a `NSMutableArray` that is `multidimensional`, something like this

```
 array[a][b][c]{number, *array*, number, number}
```

I need to replace the array in the **multidimetional** array.

I tried with **replaceObjectAtIndex** and with **removeObjectAtIndex / insert** and it crashed in both the cases.

Here is my code:

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease]; 

NSMutableArray *arrMatched = [[[[self.scoreTable objectAtIndex:a] objectAtIndex:b ] objectAtIndex:c] objectAtIndex:1];


if([arrMatched count] > 0) {
    [[[[self.scoreTable objectAtIndex:a] objectAtIndex:b ] objectAtIndex:c] replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:arr];

   // [[[[self.scoreTable objectAtIndex:a] objectAtIndex:b ] objectAtIndex:c] removeObjectAtIndex:1];

   // [[[[self.scoreTable objectAtIndex:a] objectAtIndex:b ] objectAtIndex:c] insertObject:arr atIndex:1]; }
```

Update:
I see in traces:

> 2016-07-28 23:35:15.818 wp[2213:52307] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
>   '-[__NSCFArray replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: mutating method sent
>   to immutable object'

I got also the same crash if i am replacing a NSNumber (index 0):

> ```
> [[[[self.scoreTable objectAtIndex:a] objectAtIndex:b ] objectAtIndex:c] removeObjectAtIndex:0];
>
> [[[[self.scoreTable objectAtIndex:a] objectAtIndex:b ] objectAtIndex:c]
>  insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] atIndex:0];
> ```

Update:
The inner array is created like this:

> ```
>  NSMutableArray *arrayOfLevelInfo = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]
>  autorelease];
>  [arrayOfLevelInfo addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
>  NSMutableArray *pairs = [[NSMutableArray alloc]
>  initWithCapacity:8]; [arrayOfLevelInfo addObject:pairs];  
>  [arrayOfLevelInfo addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]]; 
>  [arrayOfLevelInfo addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]]; 
>  [arrayOfLevelInfo addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
> ```

Comment: Post the crash log.

Comment: You need to make a mutable copy of the array

Comment: Looks to me like the array you have stored at index c is an NSArray and not an NSMutableArray.  Make that be an NSMutableArray, and this crash should go away.

Comment: I am not sure, i commented the lines and i replced the object at index 0 which is a NSNumber and get the same crash.

Comment: How are you creating the inner arrays?  They aren't mutable.

Comment: It doesn't matter WHAT you are trying to add/remove in that array at index c.  The problem is that THAT array you are trying to modify is an NSArray, which can't be modified.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't exist a multi dimensional mutable array in Objective C.  All the arrays are single dimensional, so you have to create all the sub-arrays:

```
self.scoreTable = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
 NSMutableArray * a = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 [self.scoreTable addObject: a];
 for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++ ) {
   NSMutableArray * b = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   [a addObject: b];
   for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
     NSMutableArray * c = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     [b addObject: c]
     for (int l = 0; l < 10; l++) {
       [c addObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt:l];
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: I do that, i created all the subarrays.

Comment: ...and your subarray for c is not mutable, but mine is.